# How to make a button inside a table execute a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple html table that displays data from a mysql table containing a list of available tournaments.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Tournament Name</th>
        <th>Platform</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Venue</th>
        <th>Judge</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Limit</th>
        <th>Register</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['nTournament'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['pTournament'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['dTournament'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['vTournament'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['jTournament'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['dTournament'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['lTournament']; ?></td>
        <td><form method="post" action="tournamentlist.php"><button type="submit" name="btn_register"></button></form></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

What I want to do is that once the current user clicks that button, the button executes a query which takes the current user's id and the tournament id of the selected row to add them to another mysql table. Something like a tournament inscription.
The query/function I want to run is:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn_register'])) {
    singup();
}
function singup() {
    global $db;
    $idUser = $_POST['idUser'];
    $idTournament= $_POST['idTournament'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO registeredCompetitor(idUser, idTournament) VALUES ('$idUser', '$idTournament')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    header('location: tournamentlist.php');
}
```

The query works just fine on it's own but I don't know if the function itself works because of the button.
Is it possible to do such thing without the use of a form? If not, What other ways are there to do something like this?

EDIT1: Button now is ready but nor the function or the query executes once it's clicked.

Comment: The normal way to do this is to make each row a form or use AJAX to submit a POST request to the server. If you're just starting out, I'd recommend wrapping the button with a `<form action="post">` and have 2 hidden fields `idUser` and `idTournament`.

Comment: Can't wrap it because <form> is not allowed as a child of <td>

Comment: ahh good point. Deleting answer. EDIT - actually, is that true? It can't be a child of <tr> but not sure about a <td>.

Comment: @waterloomatt actually, you are right. Button is ready but still won't let me execute the query, I'll update the question.

Comment: Can you please turn on error reporting in your scripts and then report back? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424/296555

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form on each row that has 2 hidden fields in it. Not sure what your DB fields are called though so you'll have to change `user_id` and `tournament_id` to something appropriate.

```
...
<td>
    <form action="post" action="the_name_of_your_php_script.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="idUser" value="<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="idTournament" value="<?php echo $row['tournament_id']; ?>">
        <button type="submit" name="btn_register"></button>
    </form>
</td>
...
```

> `Can't wrap it because <form> is not allowed as a child of <td>`

All the documentation I see online permits forms inside of `<td>`. The other alternative is to use a link instead of a form.

Comment: Using a link is actually a really good / simple solve if he can get away with that type of route.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to execute this functionality.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Tournament Name</th>
        <th>Platform</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Venue</th>
        <th>Judge</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Limit</th>
        <th>Register</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['nTournament'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['pTournament'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['dTournament'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['vTournament'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['jTournament'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['dTournament'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['lTournament']; ?></td>
        <td><button type="submit" onclick="sendRequest('<?php echo $idUser ?>','<?php echo $idTournament ?>')" name="btn_register"></button></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Javascript code

```
function sendRequest(idUser,idTournament ){
     // i am using jquery
      $.post(other_page_url,{idUser:idUser,idTournament :idTournament},function(data) 
        {
        window.location = 'tournamentlist.php';
         } )}
```

I hope it's gonna help you

Comment: What would need to be in "other_page_url"?

Comment: other_page_url is the url where you have placed the php script to store idUser and idTournament

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap this in a `<form>` inside the table, you can do it all via Javascript / Jquery if you wish.  On the html side, add the data you need to the button in data sets:

```
<td><button type="submit" name="btn_register" id="btn_register" data-user-id="<?php echo $userId ?>"  data-tournament-id="<?php echo $row['idTournament']; ?>"></button></td>
```

Then in your script, you can call the data and send to post via ajax and either load the new page after INSERT, or load as a modal, or whatever you like.  You can do something like below if loading a modal (change the load part to refresh the page if you want to go directly):

```
$('#btn_register').on('click', function () {
        var t_id = $(this).data('tournament-id');
        var u_id = $(this).data('user-id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "YourURL",
            type: "POST",
            data:{
                t_id:t_id,
                u_id:u_id
            },
            success: function (h) {
                $(".modal-title").text("Table with new stuff");
                $(".modal-body").html(h);
                $('#modal').modal();
                // lots of options here - you could even reload above if desired
            }
        })
    });
```